# Using Bootstrap, how do i achieve this horizontal tab layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap nav-tabs to do the following

[image: Example]

I'm almost there with the main HTML+CSS but I can't get the 'Overview' box to be bigger than the other boxes without throwing the entire layout. Does anyone have any ideas how I can get the Overview box to be larger than the others, and blue. This doesn't have to be on hover, just by default the tab the user is on will be bigger than the others.

I've bodged together code here - http://jsfiddle.net/csU5r/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px; vertical-align:bottom;">
  <li><a href="#home" style="color:White;">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home" style="color:White;">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home" style="color:White;">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home" style="color:White;">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

(please excuse some of the in-line styling, it'll be moved... I promise!)

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution (jsfiddle.net/gustavocorrea/3mSjy/1/ broken). I added a class in your first "li" called active and I applied some rules CSS.

Comment: This link is dead.